# Android Studio generated apk installs but doesn't open

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have installed my apk bundle that I created via Build APK(s) and it installs but won't let me open it, and it doesn't show in the menu.

I've already checked Project/App/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and Project/build.gradle and settings.gradle as well but I don't find anything odd.

android:protectionLevel="signature" is not in any of the previous files.
minifyEnabled is FALSE
I've read somewhere to edit my manifest and add  or something (I can't find the post right now). I did it, and the app began to have gradle errors, and showed me another manifest that had those lines written.

Here's my Project/App/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.multicobertura">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Multicobertura" />


</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

settings.gradle

```js
include ':app'
rootProject.name = "multicobertura"
```

I am clueless

EDIT: I tried adding "entry points"

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.multicobertura">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Multicobertura" />
    <activity
        android:name=".NewEntryPoint"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</manifest>
```

But [image: I cant build the app now]

**build.gradle**

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app build.gradle**

```js
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.multicobertura"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

EDIT2: I've already created a new android studio project, copied the files and yarn insalled the modules, built the app and failed as well. Anyone?

Comment: Your manifest does not declare any *entry points* (aka [app components](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals#Components))

Comment: <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

adding this would fix it?

Comment: the <activity> should be inside the <application>

Comment: post your app build.gradle file

Comment: Update: I've already tried deleting the proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile from app/build.gradle